# Loading problem: pokeball keeps spinning

Tags: pokemon-go

When I open Pokémon Go, after the login, appears the loading screen with a pokeball spinning...And the pokeball doesnt stop, I mean the game doesn't open.

I've tried downloading again, cleaning dads, turn the Wi-Fi off and on...
What else can I do?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as it's not asking what the spinning is, but how to fix it.

Comment: Of all the diagnostic tips for software troubleshooting I have ever tried, not once did I think of cleaning my dad.

Comment: @MadMAxJr What is "cleaning dads" even supposed to mean!? haha

Answer (score 3):

The game's servers are extremely overwhelmed at this time. Give it a few days for Niantec to beef up the servers and the hype to blow over, then things will work smoother.

Additionally, if you downloaded the APK, instead of getting the game from the PlayStore or apple store, it will probably cause problems (and may even end up in bans)... so don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the app. (double tap/hold home then swipe)
2. Turn on airplane mode
3. Open the app
4. Wait till the no connection found red banner appears on the top of the screen then turn airplane  mode off
5. It should load. :)